# mod_rewrite and hyperlinks

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, seo

I'm trying to get my head around mod_rewrite and friendly URLS.

OK, on a very basic level I have the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^register$ register.php [L]
```

This allows me to browse to www.mydomain.com/register

The hyperlink within my pages shows **register.php**. Do I have to manually change my links to ***register***?

Esentiallly, I do not want the **.php** extension on any of my links.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you must manually change the hyperlinks (or use your favourite search-and-replace tool). `mod_rewrite` can't do this for you; it can only rewrite incoming requests, not outgoing HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll need to change the URL in your code if that's not what you want to show up in the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition:

Note that `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php` rewrites all files for you which saves you typing a lot of rules ;) Offcourse you can add more validation to it by using something like `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?pageId=$1`.

Comment: Hey thank you very much for the advice. Finally getting to grips with mod_rewite!